# Changing algorithm2e keywords fonts

Tags: fonts, algorithm2e

A journal has asked me to change the font of my algorithm to Courier New. I'm able to change all except the keywords (if, then, else, *etc.*). My best solution looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        {{\fontfamily{pcr}
            \If {{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont condition}}
        }}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set each of the algorithm components individually (through settings like `\SetKwStyle`, `\SetArgSty`, `\SetDataSty`, ...), or change the font at the start of every `algorithm` automatically by adjusting `\textnormal`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithm}{\let\textnormal\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \If {condition}{true clause}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) was used to tap into `\begin{algorithm}`.

Comment: Hi, could you please give me an example of how to use \SetKwStyle to change the default font? I tried many ways but failed. Many thanks!!

Comment: @JustinCivi: You can try `\SetKwSty{texttt}` (not `\SetKwSty{\texttt}`).